# Triangle categorizer -- completely refactored and re-written

Tags: beginner, c, io

While reviewing [a C question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84775/generating-a-triangle-from-integers/84792#84792) I started writing my own implementation and in no time I had a completely refactored completely different implementation. As the asker is learning I did not want to post it, instead I ask you for further review and possibilities of improvement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int get_side(name) {
    printf("Side-%d has value: ", name);
    int value; scanf("%d", &value);
    return value;
}

bool is_valid_triangle(side_1,side_2,side_3) {
    bool all_positive = side_1 > 0 && side_2 > 0 && side_3 > 0;
    bool correct_sized_sides = side_1 + side_2 > side_3 && \
                               side_2 + side_3 > side_1 && \
                               side_3 + side_1 > side_2;
    return all_positive && correct_sized_sides;
} 

bool is_equilater(side_1,side_2,side_3) {
    return (side_1 == side_2 && side_2 == side_3);
}

bool is_isosceles(side_1,side_2,side_3) {
    return (side_1 == side_2) || (side_2 == side_3) || (side_3 == side_1);
}

bool is_scalen(side_1,side_2,side_3) {
    return ! is_isosceles(side_1,side_2,side_3);
}

const char * triangle_categorizer(side_1,side_2,side_3) {
    if (is_equilater(side_1,side_2,side_3)) {
        return "equilater";
    }

    if (is_isosceles(side_1,side_2,side_3)) {
        return "isosceles";
    }

    if (is_scalen(side_1,side_2,side_3)) {
        return "scalen";
    }
}

int main() {
    int side_1 = get_side(1);
    int side_2 = get_side(2);
    int side_3 = get_side(3);

    if (! is_valid_triangle(side_1,side_2,side_3)) {
        puts("The triangle you intered is invalid!");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("The triangle you entered is %s.\n", \
           triangle_categorizer(side_1,side_2,side_3));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few simple comments:

**Spelling:**

Triangles are either Isosceles, Equilateral, or Scalene

Also instead of using string literals, replace them with macros like so:

```
#define EQUILATERAL "equilateral"
#define ISOSCELES "isosceles"
#define SCALENE "scalene"
```

I commend you on using long names in c, as many c-programmers use 1-2 letter names for things. I might suggest adding comments to complex code, such as mentioning the fact that you are using triangle inequality in your is_valid_triangle function

I would also suggest extending this program to work with non-integers, such as long longs, doubles and the like. In addition, it may be more helpful to a user to pass in coordinates instead of side lengths. That would also allow you to not check if a triangle is valid or not, as technically all 3 point pairs form a triangle (even if it is degenerate).

Comment: Very nice point about using points instead of sides. (No pun intended. I swear.)

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple issues I can see with your implementation.

### Always validate

All the `is_*` methods require the calling of the `is_valid_triangle(...)` as a separate operation. I would recommend adding the is_valid_triangle() as part of all the triangle-type checks (even the `is_equilater` call). This will prevent the methods returning true for failing conditions... for example, the following are all nonsensical, but return true nonetheless:

```
is_equilater(0,0,0);
is_equilater(-1,-1,-1);
is_isosceles(0,0,0);
is_isosceles(10,10,10000);
```

### No-return value problems

This code has a redundant if-condition in the last check, and in has a 'logic path' which does not have a return statement:

> ```
> const char * triangle_categorizer(side_1,side_2,side_3) {
>     if (is_equilater(side_1,side_2,side_3)) {
>         return "equilater";
>     }
>
>     if (is_isosceles(side_1,side_2,side_3)) {
>         return "isosceles";
>     }
>
>     if (is_scalen(side_1,side_2,side_3)) {
>         return "scalen";
>     }
> }
> ```

There should be some form of terminating "return" expression, or, alternatively the last if-statement should be removed...:

```
const char * triangle_categorizer(int side_1, int side_2, int side_3) {
    if (is_equilater(side_1,side_2,side_3)) {
        return "equilater";
    }

    if (is_isosceles(side_1,side_2,side_3)) {
        return "isosceles";
    }

    return "scalen";
}
```

Comment: To answer your question, "how does this compile?" — in C, function parameters without an explicit type have type `int`.

Comment: Mutter mutter... thanks @GarethRees TIL that C supports default paameter types.

Comment: Not just function parameters — function return types and global variables too! (This was standardized in C89 — see §3.5.2 — but in C99 the "implicit int" rule was dropped.)

Answer (score 3):

The juxtaposition of C99 `bool` and K&R-style function parameters is… "interesting".  In the original C language, you could write functions like

```
double power(x, y)
           double x; unsigned int y; {
    double result = 1;
    while (y --> 0) {
        result *= x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

… with the type specifications being optional (defaulting to `int`).  This style of parameter lists has been out of fashion since ANSI C came out in 1989, and is allowed today only for compatibility with ancient code.  GCC and Clang would complain if you compiled using the `-pedantic` flag.

But why limit yourself to triangles of integer-length sides?  Very few geometry problems fit that mold.  You should be using `double`s for all lengths.

The way you truncated the names `is_equilater` → `is_equilateral` and `is_scalen` → `is_scalene` reminds me of [Ken Thompson's greatest regret](//stackoverflow.com/a/8391001/1157100): dropping the "e" at the end of the name of the `creat` function.

In summary, you should write

```
bool is_scalene(double side1, double side2, double side3) {
    …
}
```